# UserControl Visibility binding through ViewModel

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

Simplified architecture of my Silverlight app:

- MainPage; DataContext set to MainViewModel
- MainPage has two elements: UserControl and Rectangle
- in MainViewModel, I have two properties, UserControlVisible and RectVisible, both of type Visibility, binded to Visibility properties of those two elements in MainPage.XAML
- MainViewModel has INotifyPropertyChanged implemented

Problem is, when I set RectVisible property in MainViewModel to Visibility.Collapsed, Rectangle hides, which is fine, but when I set Visibility.Collapsed to UserControl (UserControlVisible property), it never hides!
I cannot hide that user control, and I have to do it through my ViewModel class. Why it works with Rectangle element, but not with UserControl? When I manually set Visibility to Collapsed in XAML, then it's hidden, but I have to do it through code and ViewModel object.

(edit) **Temporary sollution:**

I manually subscribed to PropertyChanged event in codebehind

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    viewmodel=new MainViewModel();
    this.DataContext = viewmodel;
    // fix for binding bug:
    viewmodel.PropertyChanged += viewmodel_PropertyChanged;
}

void viewmodel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "LoginVisible")
        loginWindowControl.Visibility = viewmodel.LoginVisible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it and I don't know if my solution will work for you.
The datacontext for my "MainPage" was different than the datacontext for my UserControl.
I was setting the datacontext for my usercontrol manually through XAML
I will give an example:

```
<local:myusercontrol  DataContext="myusercontroldatacontext" Visibiltiy="{Binding Path=VisibleProperty}"/>
```

the VisibleProperty is this case should belong to the myusercontroldatacontext, and not the the datacontext where the parent xaml is defined

Comment: sorry I didn't realize that the xml won't show up without adding the code brakets.
I added the example again.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to find a way to bind the Visibility property to the root of your user control's visuals (the Grid/Panel).

Comment: tried, but still binding doesn't work, it hides only when I set property through codebehind

Comment: care to share how you setup the binding (a subset of your XAML)?