# Setting UserControl Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a property that is not binding and cannot figure out where the problem is. Can someone please help? My Converter is running for other bound controls, so there is no issue there. When setting a break point, I never see the property IsMyControlVisible get hit.

I added this line to the property MyControlViewModels:

```
this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.IsMyControlVisible);
```

When it get hit, it causes the set of my property to be hit, but nothing happens with the visibility of my control, even though I can see the value is true. The control is completely functional, I just cannot get it to show programmatically. Also, my visibility converter works for other views, so that is not the problem.

It seems (to me) that the binding is just not set up correctly and if I can get it working, the visibility would work on the control.

My control is inside a TabControl, which is inside a Grid on my view.

I've found this post that was the closest to my problem and tried it without success:

[UserControl Visibility binding through ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351256/usercontrol-visibility-binding-through-viewmodel)

ConfigurationEditorView.xaml:

```
<ctrls:MyControl Grid.Row="0" 
    Visibility="{Binding Path=IsMyControlVisible, 
    Converter={StaticResource booleanToStringConverter},
    FallbackValue=Hidden}" />
```

ConfigurationEditorView's Constructor:

```
this.DataContext = new ConfigurationEditorViewModel();
```

ConfigurationEditorViewModel:

```
public bool IsMyControlVisible
{
    get
    {
        return this.MyControlViewModels.Count > 0;
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<MyControlViewModel> myControlViewModels 
    = new ObservableCollection<MyControlViewModel>();

public ObservableCollection<MyControlViewModel> MyControlViewModels
{
    get
    {
        return this.myControlViewModels;
    }

    set
    {
        this.myControlViewModels = value;

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.myControlViewModels);

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.IsMyControlVisible);
    }
}
```

ConfigurationEditorViewModel Constructor:

```
public ConfigurationEditorViewModel()
{
    this.MyControlViewModels.Add(new MyControlViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding items to the ObservableCollection? You are going to have to raise a property change for IsMyControlVisible whenever items are added or removed. Also, if you suspect there are problems with your bindings you should inspect the output window for binding errors.

Comment: I am raising the property change...this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.IsMyControlVisible); I will check my output and see if I see anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using boolToString converter and you actually need Visibility.

Answer (score 1):

As your code is written, you'll only get a notification if someone assigns a new instance of `ObservableCollection` to your `MyControlViewModels` property. Instead, in the setter, you would write wherever you create your view models, you would add

```
set
{
    if (myControlViewModels != null)
    {
        myControlViewModels.CollectionChanged -= OnControlViewModelsChanged;
    }

    this.myControlViewModels = value;

    this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.IsMyControlVisible);

    if (myControlViewModels != null)
    {
        myControlViewModels.CollectionChanged += OnControlViewModelsChanged;
    }
}
```

where

```
public void OnControlViewModelsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.IsMyControlVisible);
}
```

Another minor point: normally you would not have a setter for a property of type `ObservableCollection` - it would be get-only, and you would create it in the constructor. That would simplify some of your code (like not needing to unsubscribe from the change event). See for instance `ItemsControl.Items` (it doesn't use an observable collection, the pattern is the same).

Comment: I see what you are saying, but the MyControlViewModels does get assigned new instances through the view. I just believe my binding is not working some where. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [**`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can you use. The value you are trying to get is an enum called Visibility, not a string.

Comment: I tried changing my converter and it still does not work. I  believe my problem is in the binding not being wired up correctly, but I do not see where. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the property you are binding to is on the DataContext of the user control? You can check the output window in visual studio to see if there are any binding errors.

Comment: The property is in the DataContext. In code behind, I added a click event to my add button (which is used to add a new MyControlViewModel) so I could use a break point and using the following statement in the Immediate Editor: (ConfigurationEditorViewModel)this.DataContext I see IsMainframeConfigurationVisible: true. Somehow, it is not binding. I can set a breakpoint on the public property and it never gets hit when I first open the view.